# powershell windows form textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I've created a PowerShell GUI using windows form.
I'm countering a problem when I'm creating PasswordChar to the textbox, that's work only when the user clicks on the textbox.
if the user navigating to the textbox using TAB, the PasswordChar won't work.
I've tried several things, but without success.
here is my latest try:

```
$textBox5 = New-Object Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox

$textBox5.Text = "Enter your Current password:"

    $textBox5.Text = $null $textBox5.PasswordChar = '*' })

$textBox5.Add_TabIndexChanged({

    $textBox5.Text = "haha" })

$textBox5.Width = 203 
$textBox5.Height = 20 
$textBox5.location = new-object system.drawing.point(136,94) 
$textBox5.Font = "Lucida Bright,10" 
$Form.controls.Add($textBox5)
```

Comment: Check your code / formatting. These seems not functional and might even be related to why it's not working.

Comment: @marsze So, if i'm using the wrong subroutines, what is the correct use?

Comment: I just noticed that weird comment messing up your code and multiple statements on one line etc. ... clean up your code first.

Comment: It is unclear what your desired behavior is and what your problem is.

Comment: @marsze the comment in the code was deleted.
ok so the plan is to have 2 text boxes, and when i will navigate between the 2 with TAB, the text that the texxtboxes contain will be deleted.

Comment: Please include a complete, executable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from comments you are looking for something like this.

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$textbox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textbox1.Text = "Text Box 1"

$defaulttext = "Enter Password"
$textbox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
$textbox2.Location = "0,40"
$textbox2.Text = $defaulttext
$textbox2.Add_Gotfocus(
   {
       if($textbox2.Text -eq $defaulttext){
            $textbox2.Text = ""
            $textbox2.PasswordChar = "*"
        }

    }
)


$form.controls.Add($textbox1)
$form.controls.Add($textbox2)


$form.ShowDialog()
```

This code creates 2 textbox. Textbox2 has text "Enter Password" initially. Once textbox2 gets focus initial string is removed and characted typed in textbox are masked with '*'.

[initial form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgMyc.png)

[Form once textbox2 gets focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBFcQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is good to specify that it is preferable to load the assembly before creating a new object Form, so as not to generate a Type not found error

```powershell
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

Or

```powershell
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
```